# Failed to run curl command in Ansible task

Tags: ansible

I have blow ansible task yml file to install nodejs on an ubuntu system.

```
---
- name: setup nodejs
  script: curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -

- name: install nodejs
  sudo: yes
  apt:
    pkg: nodejs
    state: latest

- name: install npm
  sudo: yes
  apt:
    pkg: npm
    state: latest

- name: install yarn
  sudo: yes
  apt:
    pkg: yarn
    state: latest
```

I get below error when run `ansible-playbook`:

> fatal: [xxxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to find 'curl' in expected paths."}

The `curl` is available on the path in the remote server why it still complain about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`script` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/script_module.html) is intended to run scripts (which are first uploaded to target from the path to the target), not to execute commands on remote host.

Please read the docs:

> The local script at path will be transferred to the remote node and then executed.

---

`raw`, `command`, and [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/shell_module.html) modules are for running commands on the target (in your case `shell` is appropriate, since you use a pipe).

Answer (score 2):

Since using `script`/`shell` is not recommended, here is the approach using [`get_url` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html):

```
- name: Download setup_8.x script
  get_url: url=https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x dest=/opt mode=755
- name: Setup Node.js
  command: /opt/setup_8.x
- name: Install Node.js (JavaScript run-time environment)
  apt: name=nodejs state=present
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
- name: Setup Node.js
  shell: "curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -E -"
```